# Unable to get SpamAssassin subject rule to work

Tags: spamassassin

I'm trying to catch the hoax domain name invoices I receive for my various websites. These emails have the subject line: *[domain] Final Notice*. I've added this rule to local.cf (other rules I've added are OK) ---

```
header LOCAL_DOMAINSCAM  Subject =~ /(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(com|net|org|com\.au) Final Notice/i
score  LOCAL_DOMAINSCAM 5
describe  LOCAL_DOMAINSCAM  Hoax domain name renewal notice
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
header LOCAL_DOMAINSCAM  Subject =~ /(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(com|net|org|com\.au) Final Notice/i
```

What I'm noticing on first glance is how the Spaces are being handled at the end "Final Notice"

In my custom rules, I've always had to replace spaces with \s+
So the bit at the end I would change to `...au)\s+Final\s+Notice/i`

Another typically default I have to do to my custom rules is to add the allowance for leading white space by prepeding \s*

Resulting in:

```
header LOCAL_DOMAINSCAM  Subject =~ /\s*(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(com|net|org|com\.au)\s+Final\s+Notice/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted spamassassin since you added the rule?

service spamassassin restart

Comment: Yes, I did that. And checked mail.info to be sure that the restart was successful. And other rules I've added to local.cf are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Running it through the [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/GRumd1/1) regex tester it looks like you need to remove the \ before the first dot.

```
header LOCAL_DOMAINSCAM  Subject =~ /(domain1|domain2|domain3)\.(com|net|org|com\.au) Final Notice/i
score  LOCAL_DOMAINSCAM 5
describe  LOCAL_DOMAINSCAM  Hoax domain name renewal notice
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; but I actually tested the expression there first. The expression correctly matches the target subject lines. An unescaped dot matches *any* character. The dot is escaped because I need to match an actual dot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow user rules if that's in a personal area; local.cf should contain this line:

```
allow_user_rules 1
```

This shouldn't be a problem if your rule definition is itself in SpamAssassin's `local.cf` and you've restarted the spamd instance you're running (or whatever daemon you're using).

You also should verify that SpamAssassin is loading your rule properly (run `spamassassin -D < /path/to/test/message.eml > ~/log 2>&1` and then check your `~/log` file to ensure it's loading the rule.